# How to implement a weighted 3-way ANOVA in unbalanced design?

Tags: anova, sums-of-squares, weighted-sampling

I have implemented a three-way anova with type III sum of squares in c++. Since some of my experiments (observations) are more important (more informative), I want to give them a higher weight in my analysis. For example, an experiment which is very important has a weight of 10, and a relatively important one has a weight of 5, and so on. To implement it, I repeat such observations in respect to its corresponding weight, 10 times, 5 times, ...
I used the same concept in 2way anova, but there I used the conventional formulas of Sum of Squares, because my design was balanced. So there I just multiplied the value of each observation and the number of times I have seen that to the weight.
Here, repeating the items makes the design matrix so big and increase the computational complexity. Now the problem is that what if I don't want to repeat them, but use a weight matrix? and what if the weights are not integer values (so I really can't repeat one item 0.3 times)?
I found this formula [here](http://www.stat.umn.edu/pub/macanova/docs/manual/manchp03.pdf):

```
H^=X(X'WX)-1XW
```

So I put my weights into W matrix and used this formula. To check if it works, I used the conventional method and repeated observations as often as the weight value, and gave it to MATLAB. But I got different SS values.

Could you please kindly tell me how I should change this formula?